# How to calculate unknown array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this form but would like to get the total.
Please how can I calculate this array?

```
...While(ticket table row)
{
  <input type="text" name="ticket[][price]" id="ticket[][price]" value="12">
  <input type="text" name="ticket[][fee]" id="ticket[][fee]" value="3462">
  <select name="ticket[][qty]">
     <option value="1">1
     <option value="2">2
     <option value="3">3
     <option value="4">4
     <option value="5">5
     <option value="6">6
  </select>
}
```

Eg. $total = ticket[][price] + ticket[][fee] * ticket[][qty];

Comment: It's actually straight forward. What specifically does not work for you? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($_POST['ticket'] as $ticket) {
  $total += $ticket['price'] + $ticket['fee'] * $ticket['qty'];
}

print $total;
```